# scipy.minimize messes up my constraint function

Tags: python, loops, scipy

I am  trying to run a minimization problem in python with scipy. The goal is to minimize the distance in meters between different coordinates.

```
#dependencies
pip install haversine

import scipy.optimize as spo
import haversine as hs
from haversine import Unit
```

hs.haversine returns the distance in meters between two pairs of coordinates (latitude, longitude). For example:

```
a = (41.160716, -8.582416)
b = (41.150537, -8.586245)
hs.haversine(a, b, unit = Unit.METERS)
```

1176.3758242489466 (meters)

hs.haversine is then used in my objective function and constraint like this:

```
def objFunction(X, M):
    sum = 0
    for i in X:
        for j in M:
            sum += hs.haversine(i, j, unit = Unit.METERS)
    return sum
```

```
def constraint1(X):
    for i in range(len(X)-1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(X)):
                return hs.haversine(X[i], X[j], unit = Unit.METERS) - 40
```

The objective and constraint function both work fine on their own, but when I try to use minimize() it gives me an error.

I give my minimize() the following initial input x0 ('x_init') and a tuple of coordinates ('metro_stops') that I want to minimize the distance to:

```
x_init = ((41, -8), (41.5, -8.5))
metro_stops = ((41.160716, -8.582416), (41.150537, -8.586245))

con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
cons = [con1]

sol = spo.minimize(fun = objFunction, x0 = x_init, args = (metro_stops), method = 'SLSQP', constraints = (cons))
```

I get an error saying that the constraint function "cannot unpack a non-iterable numpy object". I can't understand why since the constraint function works fine when used outside of minimize().

Full error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-b414e685be2c> in <module>
----> 1 sol = spo.minimize(fun = objFunction, x0 = x_init, args = (metro_stops,), method = 'SLSQP', constraints = (cons))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    625         return _minimize_cobyla(fun, x0, args, constraints, **options)
    626     elif meth == 'slsqp':
--> 627         return _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
    628                                constraints, callback=callback, **options)
    629     elif meth == 'trust-constr':

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)
    328     meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
    329               for c in cons['eq']]))
--> 330     mieq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
    331                for c in cons['ineq']]))
    332     # m = The total number of constraints

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    328     meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
    329               for c in cons['eq']]))
--> 330     mieq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
    331                for c in cons['ineq']]))
    332     # m = The total number of constraints

<ipython-input-57-127f2f6960a1> in constraint1(X)
      2     for i in range(len(X)-1):
      3         for j in range(i + 1, len(X)):
----> 4                 return hs.haversine(X[i], X[j], unit = Unit.METERS) - 40

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\haversine\haversine.py in haversine(point1, point2, unit)
     86 
     87     # unpack latitude/longitude
---> 88     lat1, lng1 = point1
     89     lat2, lng2 = point2
     90 

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

Thankful for any tips

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please elaborate on what `hs.haversine` is and include it in your code snippet such that we have a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @joni Sorry, yes the haversine function is the method I use for measuring distance, one could also use geopy.distance.geodesic() for the same results

Comment: What is your constraint supposed to model? Currently, the nested loop doesn't make sense to me since the function is going to return `hs.haversine(X[0], X[1], unit=Unit.METERS)-40` anyway. That being said, it seems like `hs.haversine` expects iterables as arguments, not scalars (Note that `X[0]` and `X[1]` are scalars.)

Comment: `args = (metro_stops)` should probably be `args = (metro_stops,)`. The first one is a single object (with parentheses around it), the second one is a tuple, containing 1 element. The second one can be iterated over, the first one not. Hence the error message.

Comment: You probably mean `spo.minimize`, not simply `minimize`?

Comment: You should include the actual traceback of your error message (formatted as code); that is much more insightful, because then people can see where the error originates.

Comment: @joni The original contraint is: hs.haversine(coordinates1, coordinates2, unit = unit.METERS) > 40. However scipy wants them like this, at least from what I understood. And concerning X[0] and X[1], if X is a list/array of 2-element tuples then X[0] and X[1] are iterables though right?

Comment: @9769953 Right thank you, added the error message now, adding the , in 'args' didn't help though

Comment: Time for old-fashioned debugging then. For example, at the top of your `objFunction`, add a `print(f"{M=}")` line. And just below the `for j in M:` line, inside that inner loop, add a `print(f"{j=}")` line. That might point to where things go wrong. (You could also use a proper debugger, but for first attempts, this is just as fast and clear.) Similar for your `constraint1` function.

Comment: Since the error originates in your `constraint1` function, having a `print(f"{X=}")` line at the top of that function may be insightful. Presumably, `X` is a one-dimensional list, array or tuple of float values. Not a list, array or tuple or 2-float tuples.

Comment: @9769953 Unfortunately `constraint1` outputs the correct 2-element tuples of X[i] and X[j] when I call `constraint1(x_init)`. Now I tried forcing `hs.haversine` by changing `constraint1` to:

`return hs.haversine((X[i][0], X[i][1]), (X[j][0], X[j][1]), unit = Unit.METERS) - 40`

It works when calling the function outside of scipy (as it did before as well). But now I get a new error for the same line in constraint1. Now it's saying:


----> 6             return hs.haversine((X[i][0], X[i][1]), (X[j][0], X[j][1]), unit = Unit.METERS) - 40

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.